# Why this sw-precache for excluding some urls from caching in react service worker not working?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, express, authentication, oauth

I have an app using react/express. I ran into a conflict with passport auth via facebook login. It appears the service worker is blocking the call "mysite.com/api/auth/facebook". I also tried to workaround this problem by adding double-dash to this url like "mysite.com/__api/auth/facebook" which succeeded in the first step, but the facebook callback (to mysite.com/api/callback/facebook) failed. If I also add a double-dash for facebook callback (mysite.com/__api/callback/facebook) I got this error:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

So, it appears that I have to use sw-precache as suggested in other posts. However, I tried this sw-precache config and it didn't help me.

```
// config/sw.js
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'build/**/*.js',
    'build/**/*.css',
    'build/index.html'
  ],
  navigateFallback: '/index.html',
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^\/api\/auth\/.*/],
  cacheId: 'my-magical-cache-machine'
}
```

This is how I build it:

```
"build": "react-scripts build && sw-precache --config=sw-precache.js && copyfiles -u 1 build/**/*.* prod",
```

So, why the navigateFallbackWhitelist doesn't work for me?

UPDATE:

I figured out myself...First, sw-precache is deprecated, so I switched to sw-precache-cra, then, I just change the default navigateFallbackWhitelist to

```
navigateFallbackWhitelist: [ /^(?!\/api\/(auth|callback)\/).*/ ]
```

Actually, I misunderstood the "whitelist" initially.

Comment: are you sure this is because of the service worker? did you try deactivating it? sounds like the typical facebook whitelist stuff a lot of people asked on stackoverflow so far.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured it out now as updated.

Comment: editing a question with the answer is not a good idea, better create an answer and accept it on your own, you can do that.